# Storing a C float array in an NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, opengl-es

I am trying to store a `c-float array` in an `NSDictionary` to use later. 

I was initially using an `NSArray` to store the C-data but `NSArray` is to slow for my intentions.

**I am using the following code to wrap the arrays in the NSDictionary:**

```
[self.m_morphPositions setObject:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&positionBuff objCType:@encode(float[(self.m_countVertices * 3)])] forKey:fourCC];
```

**And retrieving the C-Float array using:**

```
float posMorphs[(self.m_countVertices*3)];

NSValue *posValues = [self.m_morphPositions objectForKey:name];

[posValues getValue:&posMorphs];
```

When I retireve the array, the values are all set to 0.0 for each index which is wrong.

*How can I fix this?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSValue` is probably intented for scalar values, not arrays for them. In this case, using `NSData` should be much easier

```
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&positionBuff length:(self.m_countVertices * 3 * sizeof(float))];
```

```
[data getBytes:posMorphs length:(self.m_countVertices * 3 * sizeof(float))];
```

Another solution is to allocate the array on the heap and use `NSValue` to store the pointer.

Comment: It works with arrays (see answer below). But `NSData` might be the better solution.

Answer (score 3):

I also think that `NSData` is probably the best solution here. But just if anybody is interested: You cannot use `@encode` with a variable sized array, because it is a *compiler directive*. Therefore

```
@encode(float[(self.m_countVertices * 3)])
```

cannot work. Actually the compiler creates the encoding for a float array of size zero here, which explains why you get nothing back when reading the `NSValue`.

But you can create the type encoding string at runtime. For a float array,
the encoding is `[<count>^f]` (see [Type Encodings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html)), so the following would work:

```
const char *enc = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%d^f]", (self.m_countVertices * 3)] UTF8String];
NSValue *val = [NSValue valueWithBytes:positionBuff objCType:enc];
```

Comment: +1 Good point about compiler directive. Nice to learn something new. However, I wonder why it doesn't issue any warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You can feed the bytes into an NSDictionary if they're wrapped in an NSData.

If you want to skip that, you would use an `NSMapTable` and `NSPointerFunctionsOpaqueMemory` (or `MallocMemory`) for the value pointer functions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is the way you are encoding your value, but it might help to encapsulate your array into a struct.

```
// Put this typedef in a header
typedef struct
{
    float values[3];
} PosValues;
```

In your code:

```
// store to NSValue
PosValues p1 = { { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 } };
NSValue *val = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&p1 objCType:@encode(PosValues)];

// retrieve from NSValue
PosValues p2;
[val getValue:&p2];

NSLog(@"%f, %f, %f", p2.values[0], p2.values[1]. p2.values[2]);
```

The benefit to this approach is that your array is kept as an *array type*. Also, these structures are assignable even though raw arrays are not:

```
PosValues p1 = { { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 } };
PosValues p2;

p2 = p1;
```